# How to write graphical programs

Tags: c++, qt4, code-structure

I have learned C++ and Qt4. I wrote one graphical program with 3000 rows and I found out that there is really complicated to keep code simple, transparent and well-structured. I like design patterns etc. because they are really effective and helps to keep code simpler and more transparent. Now I am going to write another "bigger" application but I would like to have a clear code which will be easy to edit and won't be big problem to add some enhancement etc.

I am looking for some guide, pattern, manual or experience which says how to structure code in graphical applications to be well-structured due to testing ( unit and integration ) in business logic and future edits.

If this manual will be directed to C++ and Qt it will be better but it is not main requirement.

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: I would highly recommend the book, Code Complete; http://www.cc2e.com/

Comment: @Dimitar: upvoted, but why do people insist on answering questions with comments?

Comment: @mizipzor: guess i really didnt think it was a real answer.

Comment: @Dimitar: Why doesn't this be a real answer. It is recommendation to that book. Thanks for it, I'll look at it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would highly recommend the book, Code Complete; http://www.cc2e.com/

Answer (score 3):

"C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, And Best Practices".
by Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu

It is a compilation of coding habits. Really brief, really concise, really precise, and not verbose at all. This book is as much important as GoF "Design Patterns" for me.